# Pasar valor de una funcion de una clase a textbox de un form VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

necesito pasar valores desde una funcion que tengo en una clase a varios textbox de un formulario. Intente con lo que expongo a continuación, si bien no da error no carga los valores en los textbox.

Funcion en la calse Functions

```
Public Function LoadWebConfig(PathWebConfig As String)
    Dim Server As String
    Dim BaseDatos As String
    Dim UsrSA As String
    Dim saPassword As String
    Dim KeySettings As String
    Dim Message As String
    Dim Doc As New XmlDocument

    Dim Frm As FrmMain
    Frm = New FrmMain



    Doc.Load(PathWebConfig)
    For Each xElement As XmlElement In Doc.DocumentElement
        If xElement.Name = "appSettings" Then
            For Each xNode As XmlNode In xElement.ChildNodes
                If xNode.Attributes(0).Value = "ServerName" Then
                    Server = xNode.Attributes(1).Value
                End If
                If xNode.Attributes(0).Value = "DataBaseId" Then
                    BaseDatos = xNode.Attributes(1).Value
                End If
                If xNode.Attributes(0).Value = "UserDB" Then
                    UsrSA = xNode.Attributes(1).Value
                End If
                If xNode.Attributes(0).Value = "Password" Then
                    saPassword = xNode.Attributes(1).Value
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next


    Frm.PropTxtServer = Server.ToString
    Frm.PropTxtDataBase = BaseDatos.ToString
    Frm.PropTxtUser = UsrSA.ToString
    Frm.PropTxtPassword = saPassword.ToString
End Function
```

En la clase del formulario tengo declaradas las propiedades para asiganr los valores alos textbox.
Ejemplo:

```
Public Property PropTxtDataBase() As String
    Get
        Return Txt_BaseDatos.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Txt_BaseDatos.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Load de formulario

```
Private Sub FrmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim Fn As Functions
    Dim PathWebConfig As String
    Fn = New Functions

    Txt_PathWebConfig.Text = Fn.GetIniValue("Config", "PathWebConfig", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\EBPtoGP.ini")
    If Strings.Right(Strings.Trim(Txt_PathWebConfig.Text), 1) = "\" Then
        PathWebConfig = Strings.Trim(Txt_PathWebConfig.Text) & "Web.config"
    Else
        PathWebConfig = Strings.Trim(Txt_PathWebConfig.Text) & "\Web.config"
    End If
    Fn.LoadWebConfig(PathWebConfig)
End Sub
```

Podrían darme una mano?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Si no entendes porque la duplicada es tu error, por favor usa el boton [edit] y aclara que no entendes...